# Evaluation of multilabel and multiclass data labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kaggle

are there any evaluation metrics available for multiclass-multilabel classification? 
for example, I'm taking part in the following competition at kaggle and it requires ROC AUC as evaluation metric.: http://www.kaggle.com/c/mlsp-2013-birds

Is it possible to do this using sklearn?

Answer (score 0):

There's this library from Kaggle's Director of Engineering:
https://github.com/benhamner/Metrics/tree/master/Python

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, `sklearn.metrics` includes several functions you can use for evaluating multiclass-multilabel classification models. For example `accuracy_score` can calculate the fraction of correct (i.e. all predicted labels are correct) predictions. The `hamming_loss` function can calculate the Hamming Loss, or fraction of labels that are incorrectly predicted, in a given test set. You can find an in-depth discussion of the available metrics [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).